# Creating rows in table related to 2 others

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Have models:

```
class Usdzar < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :smoothings
    has_many :smoothvals, through: :smoothings
end

class Smoothval < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :smoothprices
    has_many :usdzars, through: :smoothings
end

class Smoothing < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :usdzar
    belongs_to :smoothval

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :smoothval
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :usdzar

    before_save :create_smoothings

    def create_smoothings
    smoothval = Smoothval.find(smoothval_id) 
    1.upto(Usdzar.count) do
      Smoothing.create!(
        usdzar_id => usdzar.id,
        smoothval_id => smoothval.id,
        smprice => 99
        )
    end
end
```

Using the smoothings controller I am from the view action setting the value of the smoothval and then from the entries in this table want to perform calculations on every row in the usdzar table on price. The output I want to insert into smoothing table. Every price id should then end up with a smprice id calculated from fval and sval.

My method was a test just to get the loop working but it is failing.

Migrations:

```
class CreateSmoothings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :smoothings do |t|
      t.decimal :smprice,   :precision => 8, :scale => 5
      t.references :usdzar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :smoothval, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :smoothings, :smprice
  end
end

class CreateSmoothvals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :smoothvals do |t|
      t.decimal :fval, :precision => 2, :scale => 0
      t.decimal :sval, :precision => 2, :scale => 0
      t.string :name
      t.string :nickname

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :smoothvals, :name
  end
end

class CreateUsdzars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :usdzars do |t|
      t.date :day
      t.decimal :price,   :precision => 8, :scale => 5
      t.decimal :delta,   :precision => 8, :scale => 5

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :usdzars, :day
    add_index :usdzars, :price
  end
end
```

'localhost:3000/smoothings/new' (I am selecting the smoothval to be used to perform the calculations from a DD list:

```
<%= form_for(@smoothing) do |f| %>
  <% if @smoothing.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@smoothing.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this smoothing from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @smoothing.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :smoothvals %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :smoothval_id, Smoothval.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When submitting I get:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

      Smoothing.create!(
        usdzar_id => usdzar.id,
        smoothval_id => smoothval.id,
        smprice => 99
      )
```

My strong params:

```
params.require(:smoothing).permit(:smprice, :usdzar_id, :smoothval_id, :usdzars_attributes => [:id, :price, :delta])
```

Can someone let give me an idea why its doing this and what a better approach may be?

Answer (score 0):

In your `create_smoothings` method, the variable usdzar is not defined. The problem  is in your upto loop, change your method to this :

```
def create_smoothings
 smoothval = Smoothval.find(smoothval_id) 
 Usdzar.all.each do |usdzar|
  Smoothing.create!(
    usdzar_id => usdzar.id,
    smoothval_id => smoothval.id,
    smprice => 99
    )
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: This worked but all items were entered with nil values. I think my issue is as you have said getting the variables declared however the variables are a function of the loop so its not coming from the view but needs to be done in the model.     usdzar_id => usdzar.id,
    smoothval_id => smoothval.id,
    smprice => 99 will this not declare and assign?

Comment: why  don't you run this method on your controller, and avoid using before_save. This solution might generate an infinite loop

Comment: The maths is going to be very complex as I still need to do this, was just trying to get the loop to work. The smoothing is going to start with the difference between the price and the price the day before and apply a percentage (fval) then be added to the day before price. Then the second smoothing using the output of the first (((worked price - worked out price day before)*sval) + day before 1st smoothed price) is done so it will be very long. Maybe its best to do a trigger in PSQL? Will try this in controller and let you know

Comment: My point is that you can test this loop by calling it in your controller, without the before_save callback. Because, we don't, generally, create objects on a before_save

Comment: Thanks Othmane : I have added into the controller and got it all to work. I will try and update it to show you. New at this need to read more about how to use SO.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I got to using controller: I will move it to model but got it working for now

# POST /smoothings
  def create

```
@sv = Smoothval.find(smoothing_params[:smoothval_id])

Usdzar.all.each do |usdzar|
    Smoothing.create!(
    usdzar_id: usdzar.id,
    smoothval_id: @sv.id,
    smprice: 99
    )
end
redirect_to smoothings_url, notice: 'Smoothings successfully created.'
```

end

## Not using  nested attributes_for

Answer (score 0):

Done in the Controller

# POST /smoothings
  def create

```
sv = Smoothval.find(smoothing_params[:smoothval_id])
fval = sv.fval
sval = sv.sval



Usdzar.all.each do |usdzar|

    if usdzar.id == 1
      prevusdzar = usdzar.price
      prevfirstsmprice = usdzar.price
    else
      previd = (usdzar.id) - 1
      prevusdzar = Usdzar.find(previd).price
      prevfirstsmprice = Smoothing.find(previd).firstsmprice
    end

    firstsmprice = (((fval * usdzar.delta)/100) + prevusdzar)

    firstsmdelta = firstsmprice - prevfirstsmprice

    finalsmprice = (((sval * firstsmdelta)/100) + prevfirstsmprice)

    Smoothing.create!(
      usdzar_id: usdzar.id,
      smoothval_id: sv.id,
      firstsmprice: firstsmprice,
      firstsmdelta: firstsmdelta,
      finalsmprice: finalsmprice
    )
end


redirect_to smoothings_url, notice: 'Smoothings successfully created.'
```

end

If I were to add it to the model what action would I use before the save?
I am not finished doing calculation so its getting quite long, probable need some comments.